# Powershell file listing colors

Tags: powershell

In Powershell 7 it is possible to configure the colors of certain filetypes in a file listing (get-childitem) by configuring `$PSStyle.FileInfo.Extension`. Is there any way to highlight dotfiles (those beginning with a dot without another extension)?